# Tomcat 9 logs output redirection

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I installed Tomcat 9 for Windows 11 and I want to know how can I redirect `system.out.println` as in Unix (Catalina.out).
I read in a lot of forums (p.e swallowOutput="true") but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all `stdout` in `<tomcat-install>/logs/catalina*.log`

You control log-files filenames in `<tomcat-install>/conf/logging.properties`

Read more about logging management [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html).

Specifically:

> Console
>
> When running Tomcat on unixes, the console output is usually
> redirected to the file named catalina.out. The name is configurable
> using an environment variable. (See the startup scripts). Whatever is
> written to System.err/out will be caught into that file. That may
> include:
>
> ```
> Uncaught exceptions printed by java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(..)
> Thread dumps, if you requested them via a system signal
> ```
>
> When running as a service on Windows, the console output is also
> caught and redirected, but the file names are different.
>
> The default logging configuration in Apache Tomcat writes the same
> messages to the console and to a log file. This is great when using
> Tomcat for development, but usually is not needed in production.
>
> Old applications that still use System.out or System.err can be
> tricked by setting swallowOutput attribute on a Context. If the
> attribute is set to true, the calls to System.out/err during request
> processing will be intercepted, and their output will be fed to the
> logging subsystem using the javax.servlet.ServletContext.log(...)
> calls. Note, that the swallowOutput feature is actually a trick, and
> it has its limitations. It works only with direct calls to
> System.out/err, and only during request processing cycle. It may not
> work in other threads that might be created by the application. It
> cannot be used to intercept logging frameworks that themselves write
> to the system streams, as those start early and may obtain a direct
> reference to the streams before the redirection takes place.